# Does anyone know, or know how to determine, the dimensions of the Samsung Galaxy S6+ screen in pixels?

Tags: wallpaper

The reason I want to know is because I want to make a wallpaper for my girlfriend that exactly fits the screen

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices allow, under Developer Options, the ability to mark screen locations.

See Settings > Developer Options > Input

Select
Show Touches,
Show pointer location

Move to the points desired, and note their coordinates.

If you find the constant coordinates undesitreable, turn OFF the options after the operation is complete to your satisfaction.

To turn on Developer Options if needed:

1. Go to app drawer and open Settings
2. Go to bottom and tap About device
3. Tap repeatedly Build number 7 times. Starting at 3rd tap, you'll see a toast saying You are now X steps away from being a developer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6_plus-7270.php), Galaxy S6 plus is equipped with a **5.5 inch, 1080x1920 screen** at 401 DPI.

Not much info can be found for it, as it seems to be a carrier-specific model.

Answer (score -1):

@GreedySkull

I think what you mean is the resolution

The screen is **5.1 inch** high resolution 
Quad HD **1440×2560 pixel** display
 with **577 pixels per inch**.

Ensure the wallpaper you're making has a size of 1440×2560 so as to fit screen correctly